# Can't seem to get fortran executable to run correctly through python

Tags: python, fortran, subprocess, os.system

I have read a bunch of different topics on SO and other sites and cannot get a direct answer to my question/problem. Currently I have this python script that runs completely fine, with the exception of no calls made to run a fortran program are working correctly. I have tried using subprocess commands, os.system commands, opening bash script files that are opened through python, and no luck. Here are some examples and errors I'm getting.

One attmept:

```
subprocess.Popen(["sh", "{0}{1}".format(SCRIPTS,"qlmtconvertf.sh"), "qlmt"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This gives an error that the program has trouble reading the file correctly.

```
    forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 1, file /home/akoufos/lapw/Ar/lda/bcc55_mt1.5_lo_e8_o4/DOS/lat70/qlmt
```

Another attempt:

```
subprocess.Popen(["./{0}{1}".format(SOURCE,"qlmtconvertf"), "qlmt"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This gives an error of not finding the file.

```
    File "/home/akoufos/lapw/Scripts_Plots/LAPWanalysis.py", line 59, in DOS
subprocess.Popen(["./{0}{1}".format(SOURCE,"qlmtconvertf"), "qlmt"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Yet another attempt:

```
os.system("{0}{1}".format(SOURCE,"qlmtconvertf qlmt"))
```

This gives an error equivalent to the first example. In all examples SOURCE="/home/myusername/lapw/Source/", where the fortran source files are, SCRIPTS="/home/myusername/lapw/Scripts_Plots/", where I have other files and the python scripts in, qlmtconvertf is a compiled fortran program, and qlmt is a file the qlmtconvertf reads. This source code works completely fine if I call it in the shell, like I have done countless times, but I'm trying to automate calling these codes. I have written a bash script as well, that does what I need, but I'm trying to do everything through python instead. Any ideas, suggestions, or answers to what I am doing incorrectly and what is going on would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

**EDIT:** I got it working with the suggestion given below by Francis. I had to keep the complete paths (i.e. /home/username/etc) and the `os.path.join` to call the program correctly.

```
    import os.path
    LAPW = "/home/myusername/lapw/"
    SOURCE = os.path.join(LAPW,'Source')
    SCRIPTS = os.path.join(LAPW,'Scripts_Plots')
    QLMTCONVERT = os.path.join(SOURCE,'qlmtconvertf')
    qargs = [QLMTCONVERT,'qlmt']
    #CALLING PROGRAM
    subprocess.Popen(qargs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input=None)
```

To get it to work correctly I had to also close the 'qlmt' file I had created during the python script. Also I am working in the directory that contains the 'qlmt' file.

(**edit** Also added `.communicate(input=None)` to the end of the subprocess. This was unnecessary for this process call, but it was important for a latter one I made in the script that tried to use a file the process was creating. From my understanding the `.communicate` talks to the process and basically waits for it to finish before the next python line is executed. Similar to `.wait()`, but more advanced. If someone who understands this more wants to elaborate, please feel free. **edit**)

I'm not exactly sure why this method worked, but using strings as inputs for the subprocess was giving errors. If any one has any insight on this I would be very thankful if you could pass on your knowledge. Thank you everyone for the help.

Comment: Have you tried `shell=True`?  I usually find that necessary when calling external programs.

Comment: It's funny how you write these posts, look them over like 20 times and still forget to mention things. I have tried `shell=True` on the second example, with and without the `./`. Neither seems to work. I have also tried using `~/lapw` as the folder name instead of full path. Again neither way gives any more helpful errors. Trying it on the first example opens the shell prompt and doesn't seem to work either, but doesn't run the program. I'll look into this more as it seems the qlmtconvert is not being called. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried to change current working directory to the directory where the executable resides before attempting to run the executable? I have used several fortran program that expect to be run from their directory.

Comment: @arifwn: No I had not, but this should not be a problem, as I suggested above that the program runs fine if I call it in the shell alone. i.e. I call `/home/myusername/lapw/Source/qlmtconvertf qlmt` from the shell while working in the directory that contains 'qlmt'. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @falconskull:  Yep, sometimes there's just too much to remember.  Glad you seem to have gotten a solution.  FWIW, I tried to run a very simple FORTRAN program from a Python program using `subprocess` calls (both `.call()` and `.Popen()`) and found I needed `shell=True` to make it work.  However, you seem to be on Windows (to which I don't have access right now) and I'm on Linux, so YMMV.

Comment: @GreenMatt: Oh actually I probably should have mentioned that as well haha. I'm actually on Fedora 15. Thanks for your feedback. From what I've been reading the `shell=True` is potentially bad, so I was trying to avoid that as much as possible. Luckily I didn't need it, but I'm curious as to why I don't need it, but you do for your programs. Somehow, it seems that even if you understand 99% of what you're doing with computers, that 1% can still cause such major headaches!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot a slash in your filenames:

`"{0}{1}".format(SOURCE,"qlmtconvertf qlmt") == '/home/myusername/lapw/Sourceqlmtconvertf qlmt'`

I assume you mean this?

`"{0}/{1}".format(SOURCE,"qlmtconvertf qlmt") == '/home/myusername/lapw/Source/qlmtconvertf qlmt'`

I recommend using [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) rather than direct string construction for pathname creation:

```
import os.path

executable = os.path.join(SOURCE, 'qlmtconvertf')
args = ['qlmt']

subprocess.Popen(executable+args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: I actually have the `/` I just forgot to add that in the variables I gave up top. Sorry for the confusion. However, I didn't realize the `os.path.join` option. I will start using that and will try that out now. Thank you.

Comment: Update: This option seemed to help. However, I don't quite understand why this works, but making the paths as strings that are the exact same output as the `os.path.join` doesn't work. Do you have any insight on this? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Double-check (with an assert statement) that the strings are actually the same. `os.path.join` is intelligent about joining path segments in an os-dependent way, but it still returns a string.

Comment: I'm not going to bother to test it, as it's working with your method. I might as well use the more correct methods for these things than the string way! I've been adjusting all my scripts to use this way and things are working better and making my scripts a little easier to read. So I'm extremely grateful for your help!